# Nintagrate error. Need help. Wolfram Matematica

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm doing school project and I have a problem during compilation.
[image]

Is there anyone who could help me find solution? :)

Comment: Please post code, not images

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a closed form solution to your integral. You can avoid any convergence issues by directly evaluating it. The integral can be directly evaluated with:

```
2/l*Integrate[1/Sqrt[2 π]*Exp[(-5*(x - 5)^2)/2]*Sin[(n*π*x)/l], {x, 0, l}]
(*(1/(2 Sqrt[5] l))E^(-((n π (50 I l + n π))/(
  10 l^2))) (-I Erf[(-25 l + I n π)/(Sqrt[10] l)] + 
   I Erf[(5 (-5 + l) l + I n π)/(Sqrt[10] l)] + 
   E^((10 I n π)/
    l) (Erfi[(-25 I l + n π)/(Sqrt[10] l)] - 
      Erfi[(5 I (-5 + l) l + n π)/(Sqrt[10] l)]))*)
```

You can now easily find a table of values for each `n` using:

```
With[{l = 15}, 
 N@Table[1/(2 Sqrt[5] l)
     E^(-((n π (50 I l + n π))/(
     10 l^2))) (-I Erf[(-25 l + I n π)/(Sqrt[10] l)] + 
      I Erf[(5 (-5 + l) l + I n π)/(Sqrt[10] l)] + 
      E^((10 I n π)/
       l) (Erfi[(-25 I l + n π)/(Sqrt[10] l)] - 
         Erfi[(5 I (-5 + l) l + n π)/(Sqrt[10] l)])), {n, 40}]]
```